# How does Chrome proceed after "SSL alert number 46"?

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, openssl, alert

Say, you have a webserver that you access with Chrome.

The webserver does not provide a valid certificate, so Chrome will show up the warning:

[image: cert warning]

In addition, the server receives an alert which indicates this error back to the server:

```
error:14094416:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert certificate unknown
```

This alert is fatal for the connection, so the server closes it down.

But does anyone know how the exact behavior is **after** you click `Advanced` → `Proceed to localhost`? I'd expect that the error message `sslv3 alert certificate unknown` is no longer sent by the browser, but I can see spot it in the server's traces. This error leads to closing of the connection. **However**, not all connections seem to be closed: the website is loaded properly.

Is there a fall-back such as "use only 1 TCP connection for this server" or the like? What does Chrome exactly do after you accept the risk?

**I'm not interested in fixing the certificate errors.** I just want to know what does **exactly** happen between client and server after you hit `Proceed to localhost`.